# Shut up multi-character constant warning

Tags: c, clang

For very specific reasons, I have an enum of this kind:

```
typedef enum RSGameType
{
    RSGameTypeUnknown = 0,
    RSGameType1v1 = '1v1',
    RSGameType2v2 = '2v2',
    RSGameType3v3 = '3v3',
    RSGameType4v4 = '4v4',
    RSGameTypeCustom = 'Cust'
} RSGameType;
```

However, Clang warns me about 'multi-character constants' on each item except 'Cust' (because it's a 4-character constant I suppose).

Is there a right way to shut up these warnings, aside from using the numeric equivalent? Prepending a null (`'\x001v1'`) has no effect, though appending one works (but that's undesirable since the values aren't accurate anymore).

Comment: `RSGameType3v3 = '3v2',` -- is that a typo?

Comment: @Keith, yes, it is, as was '4v2'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the flag `-Wno-multichar`. There is also `-Wfour-char-constants`, disabled by default and that's why you don't see it.

Answer (score 7):

Multi-character constants are not portable; their values are implementation-defined.  The language doesn't even guarantee that `'1v1'` and `'2v2'` have distinct values.  That's not likely to be an issue, but if you ever need to share `RSGameType` values across code compiled by different compilers, you could be in trouble.

I presume you're already aware of all this.

But here's a solution that isn't affected by implementation-defined behavior:

```
#define CHAR3(c0, c1, c2)     (((c0)<<16) | ((c1)<<8) | (c2))
#define CHAR4(c0, c1, c2, c3) (((c0)<<24) | ((c1)<<16) | ((c2)<<8) | (c3))

typedef enum RSGameType
{
    RSGameTypeUnknown = 0,
    RSGameType1v1     = CHAR3('1', 'v', '1'),
    RSGameType2v2     = CHAR3('2', 'v', '2'),
    RSGameType3v3     = CHAR3('3', 'v', '3'),
    RSGameType4v4     = CHAR3('4', 'v', '4'),
    RSGameTypeCustom  = CHAR4('C', 'u', 's', 't')
} RSGameType;
```

Comment: @blueshift: I think this version is better.

Comment: How can `'1v1'` and `'2v2'` have the same value? Regardless of endianess or byte/bit size of the involved types (int and char), shouldn't the value still be different in either case?

Comment: @Mecki: The value of any multi-character constant is implementation-defined; the Standard doesn't even make any recommendations beyond that. I can't think of any reason for a compiler to give `1v1` and `2v2` the same values (unless the compiler developers are perversely trying to discourage their use), but nothing in the standard forbids it. See section 6.4.4.4 paragraph 10 in [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Another fun thing you can do to make a multi-character constant is deference a fixed-width string as if it were an integer of the size you're trying to make.  For example:

```
typedef unsigned long uint32;
typedef unsigned long long uint64;

uint32 make4ByteUIntegerFromChars( const char *convert ) {
    // check that strlen( convert ) == 4 if you like

    return * (uint32 *) convert;
}

uint64 make8ByteUIntegerFromChars( const char *convert ) {
    // check that strlen( convert ) == 8 if you like

    return * (uint64 *) convert;
}
```